# Why is the Faraday tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ antisymmetric?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

I was wondering if it follows from these relations 
$$ a_{\mu}u^{\mu}=0 $$
$$ u_{\mu}u^{\mu}=-1 $$
$$ ma^{\mu}=F_{\mathbf{\nu}}^{\mu}u^{\nu} $$
That 
$$ F^{\mu\nu}=-F^{\nu\mu}~? $$

Comment: Just contract both sides of your third equation by $u_\mu$ . Then $F^{\mu\nu} u_\mu u_\nu = 0$ for all $u$.

Comment: Why should it hold for all $u$?

Comment: @knzhou to be somewhat pedantic: your argument only proves that the symmetric part of $F$ does not contribute to the motion of test particles. In principle, there is more to electrodynamics than the motion of test particles, and therefore the symmetric part of $F$ is not really fixed to zero by your reasoning. A more complete answer is that $F$ is skew by definition.

Answer (score 1):

The field-strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ is in fact the curvature of the $U(1)$-valued connection, $A = A_\mu \mathrm dx^\mu$. In the special case of a one-dimensional Abelian Lie group, we have,

$$F = \mathrm dA = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu)\mathrm dx^\mu \wedge \mathrm dx^\nu.$$

The anti-symmetry is explained by others by referring to physical arguments, but there is also the geometric one, as aforementioned, which you can learn more about in any book on forms.

Comment: Is there a specific book you recommend to supplement your answer here?

Comment: Though the explanation is completely correct, it would be interesting to think about how much this mathematical formalism is constrained by the physical reality it is used to model. That is, for example, what implications would a symmetric part induce (it would destroy the gauge invariance of F for example but then, why do we want it to be U(1) gauge invariant? and then the physically interesting part begins...).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the validity of $\:F^{\mu\nu} u_\mu u_\nu = 0\:$<sup>(1)</sup> for any  $\:u_\mu\:$ is that the electromagnetic force is a pure force,  where a force is called pure if it doesn't change the rest mass $\:m_{o}\:$ of  any particle moving with any (subluminal) velocity. This demand is equivalent to the Minkowski pseudo-orthogonality of  the electromagnetic force 4-vector $\:\mathbf{F}\:$ to any velocity 4-vector $\:\mathbf{U}$.<sup>(2)</sup>

---

<sup>(1)
derived by @knzhou in his comment</sup>

---

<sup>(2)
take a look in my answer therein : [What does it mean that the electromagnetic tensor is anti-symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274416/what-does-it-mean-that-the-electromagnetic-tensor-is-anti-symmetric/274747#274747).</sup>