# Why is the Electromagnetic Field Strength Antisymmetric?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

In the book "*Relativity: Special, General and Cosmological*", Rindler introduces the Electromagnetic Field Strength by

\begin{equation}
F_ \mu = \frac{q}{c} E_ {\mu \nu} U ^\nu
\end{equation}

where $F_ \mu$ is a 4-force over a particle and $U ^ \nu$ is a 4-velocity of a particle. Rindler states if the 4-Force is rest mass preserving, i.e if the mass $m$ of the particle is constant, $m = const$, so the 4-force must satisfy

\begin{equation}
 F_ \mu U^\mu = 0
\end{equation}

then we have

\begin{equation}
E_ {\mu \nu} U ^\nu U^\mu = 0
\end{equation}

for all $U ^ \mu$.

By this result, rindler states that the electromagnetic tensor must be antisymmetric, $E_ {\mu \nu} = - E_ {\nu \mu}$.

EDIT -   My problem is: I know that assuming $E _{\mu \nu} $ is antisymmetric and $U^\mu U^\nu$ is symmetric implies $E _{\mu \nu} U^\mu U^\nu = 0$. But if I assume only the symmetry of $U^\mu U^\nu$  and that $E _{\mu \nu}U^\mu U^\nu = 0$ , how I obtain the result that $E_{\mu \nu}$ is antisymmetric, i.e, that $E_{\mu \nu } = - E_{\nu \mu}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate : [What does it mean that the electromagnetic tensor is anti-symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274416/what-does-it-mean-that-the-electromagnetic-tensor-is-anti-symmetric/274747#274747).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean that the electromagnetic tensor is anti-symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274416/what-does-it-mean-that-the-electromagnetic-tensor-is-anti-symmetric)

Comment: @probably_someone I've edited the question to specify my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a standard result for bilinear maps $E$ that
$$E(u,u)=0\;\forall u\iff E(u,v) = -E(v,u)\;\forall u,v$$

The part that's slightly less obvious is going from left to right, though it's still just a one-liner:
$$
0 = E(u+v,u+v) = E(u,u) + E(u,v) + E(v,u) + E(v,v) = E(u,v) + E(v,u)
$$

Comment: this explains the relation in a antisymmetric tensor, but don't explain why the condition $E_{\mu \nu} U^\mu U^\nu = 0 $ implies this antisymmetry

Comment: @Lil'Gravity The bilinear map in question is $E(x,y)=E_{\mu\nu}x^\mu y^\nu$, so the condition $E_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu=0$ can be rewritten as $E(U,U)=0$.

Comment: @Lil'Gravity From there we have that $E(U,V)=-E(V,U)$, which is rewritten as $E_{\mu\nu}U^\mu V^\nu=-E_{\mu\nu}V^\mu U^\nu$. Since both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are contracted, we can relabel them however we want, so in particular if we swap $\mu$ with $\nu$ on the right-hand side, we get $E_{\mu\nu}U^\mu V^\nu=-E_{\nu\mu}V^\nu U^\mu$. The components of $U$ and $V$, being scalars, commute, so we switch them and get $E_{\mu\nu}U^\mu V^\nu=-E_{\nu\mu}U^\mu V^\nu$. Since this is true for all $U$ and $V$, we can then say that $E_{\mu\nu}=-E_{\nu\mu}$.

Comment: My mind is clear now, thanks