# Antisymmetry of Electromagnetic tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

From Mueller-Kirsten's *Electrodynamics*, the electromagnetic tensor is constructed by writing out all components of the field strengths $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\phi-\frac{\partial\mathbf{A}}{\partial t}=-c\left(\boldsymbol{\nabla}A^0+\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial x_0}\right)$ and $\mathbf{B}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\mathbf{A}.$ I am seeking any physical implication that the antisymmetry of this tensor would imply. In other words, apart from the mathematical structure of electromagnetic theory, what is the physical requirement that the $F_{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetry? My priority is the physical aspect of this property, but any mathematical explanation (ex. from the perspective of gauge theory) is welcome too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean that the electromagnetic tensor is anti-symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/274416/)

Answer (score 1):

Unable to comment due to reputation. But check out this possible duplicate: [What does it mean that the electromagnetic tensor is anti-symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/274416/289543)
There is a detailed accepted answer therein.

Comment: Welcome to PSE before 6 months. You must wait to gain enough reputation to comment. It's weird to upvote comments. I downvoted your answer which must be deleted by the site moderation.