# Lorentz covariant but Lorentz inconsistent $4$-forces?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, vectors, covariance

We often say that the benefit of relativistic index notation is that we can write down equations of motion that are automatically Lorentz covariant. However, I'm starting to feel that there are many Lorentz covariant equations of motion that we can write down that are nevertheless "Lorentz inconsistent" in some sense. Throughout, I have in mind that the background metric is Minkowski for simplicity.

The main idea to me is that for massive particles, we have that $$u^\mu u_\mu = c^2,$$ so that $\frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} u_\mu = 0$.

Many of the familiar Lorentz covariant equations of motion are consistent with the constraint $\frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} u_\mu = 0$. For example, the Lorentz force of $$m \frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} = F^{\mu \nu} u_{\nu}$$ is consistent with $\frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} u_\mu = 0$ because $F^{\mu \nu}$ is antisymmetric.

However, it feels like we are generically able to write down Lorentz covariant equations of motion that are inconsistent with this constraint!

For example, I could write down $m \frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} = K^{\mu \nu} u_{\nu}$ where $K^{\mu \nu}$ *wasn't* an antisymmetric tensor. For example, maybe $K^{\mu \nu}$  is the stress-energy tensor for some field theory.

Another example might be $$m \frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} = H^\mu$$ where $H^\mu$ is some $4$-force; an example might be where I have two particles with four velocity $u^\mu$ and $v^\mu$; then if the force on one is proportional to the $4$-vector of the other, we get Lorentz covariant equations of motion $m \frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} = v^\mu$ and $m \frac{d v^\mu}{d \tau} = u^\mu$ that are nevertheless generically inconsistent with the constraints $\frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} u_\mu = 0$ and $\frac{d v^\mu}{d \tau} v_\mu = 0$.

---

Is it correct that these Lorentz covariant equations of motion are somehow "Lorentz inconsistent?" If so, is there a nice way to avoid this inconsistency -- for example, is it that if we start with a Lorentz invariant Lagrangian, then the resulting equations of motion are guaranteed to satisfy this consistency condition $\frac{d u^\mu}{d \tau} u_\mu = 0$?

Comment: You're mixing two different meanings of "Lorentz" as an adjective. Lorentz covariant refers to equation forms being the same in all inertial frames, just with transformed quantities. Lorentz force refers to the usual formula for EM force on charged particle. These two uses of "Lorentz" as adjective do not imply each other. So it is possible to have a Lorentz-covariant equation that does not obey the Lorentz formula for EM force, or a Lorentz covariant equation that does not conserve $u^\mu u_\mu$.

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks. I agree that the two uses of Lorentz don't imply eachother. I guess I was feeling that equations that don't conserve the pseudonorm of $u^\mu$ are somehow unphysical, and that the conservation of the pseudonorm of $u^\mu$ is an additional, important constraint beyond Lorentz covariance.

Comment: But that *is* the case. Four-velocity pseudonorm can't change in time, this follows from its definition. An equation which involves $u^\mu$ but does not respect this constraint can be Lorentz-covariant, but is wrong and does not describe any actual four-velocity.

Comment: @JánLalinský I agree, and that was in part what I was asking -- is such a Lorentz-covariant equation that doesn't preserve the four-velocity pseudonorm fundamentally incorrect? The other part of the question was whether there might be a nice way to avoid such incorrect equations of motion, like starting from a Lorentz invariant Lagrangian. That still isn't quite clear to me, yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the "Lorentz inconsistent" forces you mention; they just change the mass of the particle. Specifically, we have $p^\mu p_\mu = m^2 u^\mu u_\mu = m^2$, so differentiating both sides with respect to $\tau$ gives
$$\frac{dm}{d\tau} = f^\mu u_\mu.$$
For example, the force that corresponds to "putting a pan on the stove" has only $f^0$ nonzero in the stove's rest frame, and it indeed increases the pan's rest mass.

Of course, if you derive the force from a relativistically covariant Lagrangian with fixed particle mass $m$, then it must automatically satisfy $f^\mu u_\mu = 0$. Here are some examples of this:

- Minimal coupling to a scalar field via $L \supset \phi$: you get
  $$f^\mu \propto \partial^\mu \phi - u^\mu u_\nu \partial^\nu \phi$$
  which indeed satisfies the constraint. More generally, if you have any force $f'^\mu$ you can modify it to satisfy the constraint by defining $f^\mu = f'^\mu - u^\mu u_\nu f'^\nu$.
- Minimal coupling to a vector field via $L \supset u^\mu A_\mu$: you get $$f^\mu \propto \partial_{[\mu} A_{\nu]} u^\nu$$ which automatically satisfies the constraint. More generally, minimal couplings to [higher spin fields](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.21.358) have consistency issues, but would in principle yield $$f^\mu \propto \partial_{[\mu} A_{\nu_1] \nu_2 \cdots \nu_k} u^{\nu_1} \cdots u^{\nu_k}$$ which also automatically satisfy the constraint.
- Minimal coupling to a rank $2$ tensor field via $L \supset \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} u^\mu u^\nu}$: you get the geodesic equation
  $$f^\mu \propto \Gamma^\mu_{\rho \sigma} u^\rho u^\sigma$$
  which also automatically satisfies the constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I include $\phi$ in my Lagrangian, viewing it as a function of $x^\mu$, I only seem to get the contribution $\partial^\mu \phi$ and not the second piece of $- u^\mu u_\nu \partial^\nu \phi$. I'm happy about minimal coupling to the vector field. For your example with the rank $2$ tensor, are $u^\mu$ and $u_\mu$ still related by the Minkowski metric? It's also not clear to me that $ u_\mu \Gamma^\mu_{\rho \sigma} u^\rho u^\sigma = 0$ from the definition of the Christoffel symbols.

Comment: For the scalar, don't forget that the presence of this term also affects the canonical momentum. In other words, $\partial L / \partial \dot{x}^\mu$ is no longer the same thing as the relativistic four-momentum $p^\mu = m u^\mu$.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't $\partial \phi / \partial \dot{x}^\mu=0$? Let $L_{kin}$ be the kinetic Lagrangian for the particle of $-\frac{1}{\gamma} mc^2$. Then $\partial(L_{kin}+ \phi) / \partial \dot{x}^\mu$ is still equal to $\partial L_{kin} / \partial \dot{x}^\mu$, so the canonical momentum of $L_{kin}+ \phi$ is the same as the relativistic four-momentum given by $\partial L_{kin} / \partial \dot{x}^\mu$.

Comment: Okay, I should've added more details. To get a Lorentz invariant action, you need to have a term $\int \phi(x^\mu) \, d \tau$ where $\tau$ is proper time. So if you're parametrizing by the particle's 3-position, the Lagrangian has to be $L \supset \phi(\mathbf{x}(t)) \sqrt{1-|\mathbf{v}(t)|^2}$ which does depend on $\mathbf{v}(t)$.

Comment: @user196574 : *...the force that corresponds to "putting a pan on the stove...* was called by the not in use term 'heatlike force' as opposed to the term 'proper force'. A proper force, like the Lorentz force, doesn't change the rest mass of a particle. See in the bottom of my answer here : [What does it mean that the electromagnetic tensor is anti-symmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/274416/).

Comment: @knzhou Thanks, I think I'm on board that a term $\phi/\gamma$ in the Lagrangian gives a Lorentz invariant action.

Comment: I'm still a little confused by the rank 2 tensor field.  I'm pretty tempted that the geodesic equation only conserves $u^\mu u^\nu g_{\mu \nu}$, not $u^\mu u^\nu \Lambda_{\mu \nu}$. This is a little confusing to me because this seems to contradict your statement that a relativistically covariant Lagrangian with fixed particle mass will have equations of motion satisfying $f^\mu u_\mu = 0$.

Comment: I think when we start from a parametrization invariant action, the resulting equations of motion do not contain information about $u^\mu u_\mu$.

Comment: @user196574 You mean if we define $u^\mu = dx^\mu/d\lambda$ for an _arbitrary_ parameter $\lambda$? In that case, of course it doesn't. By adjusting $\lambda$ you can make $u^\mu u_\mu$ whatever you want. Throughout my answer I am assuming the usual definition $u^\mu = dx^\mu/d\tau$ where $\tau$ is specifically the proper time. In that case $u^\mu u_\mu$ is fixed by $1$ by definition.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks, I think I'm slowly coming to understand. When someone integrates against $\tau$ in an action, should I not view $\tau$ as a dummy integration variable?

Comment: For example, if $S = \int d\tau \sqrt{\frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau} \frac{d x_\mu}{d \tau}}$, I would naively say the resulting equation of motion is $\frac{d u^\mu}{d\tau} -\frac{u^\mu u_\nu}{u^\alpha u_\alpha} \frac{d u^\nu}{d\tau}  = 0$. On contracting with $u_\mu$, we get $0=0$. That is, the equations of motion don't tell us that $\frac{d}{d \tau} u^\mu u_\mu = 0$. Furthermore, the equations of motion seem underconstrained, so potentially the extra constraint of $u^\mu u_\mu = \text{const}$ needs to be imposed by hand to get a unique solution given the initial data.

Comment: However, I agree that "by the definition of $\tau$" a quantity like $u^\mu u_\mu$ should be fixed to $1$. Should my point of view be that when I write something like $S = \int d\tau \sqrt{\frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau} \frac{d x_\mu}{d \tau}}$, $\tau$ is a dummy variable, but once I have my equations of motion, I can choose to impose that $\tau$ is the proper time?

Comment: @user196574 When you write that sort of action, I would recommend calling the integration variable something else, like $\lambda$, to avoid confusion. As you ay, after you extract the equations of motion, you may set $\lambda$ to be whatever you want, e.g. you can set it equal to the proper time $\tau$.

Comment: @user196574 That's why my answer focused on the rate of change of $p^\mu p_\mu$ -- because I was using a definition where $u^\mu u_\mu$ _can't_ change.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks, I think I'm happy with everything and thank you for your patience. I've posted below an explicit work-through of your rank-2 tensor field $g$; I had been suspicious of it because the geodesic equation shouldn't generically preserve $\eta_{\mu \nu} u^\mu u^\nu$; the resolution is that when we use the parametrization $\lambda = \tau$ with $\tau$ the proper time $d\tau^2 = \eta_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$, we actually don't quite get the geodesic equation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment working out knzhou's example of coupling to a rank-2 tensor field $g$.

I'll use primes to denote differentiation with respect to $\lambda$. Consider a parametrization-invariant action $S = \int d\lambda \left[ \sqrt{\eta_{\mu \nu} x'^\mu x'^\nu}+\xi \sqrt{g_{\mu \nu} x'^\mu x'^\nu}\right]$. In the following, I'll use the shorthand $x'^2 = \eta_{\mu \nu} x'^\mu x'^\nu$ and $x_g'^2 = g_{\mu \nu} x'^\mu x'^\nu$ to reduce the number of indices. I'll use the lower-index notation $x'_\mu = \eta_{\mu \nu} x'^\nu$ with $\eta$, not $g$.

The resulting equations of motion are

$$\frac{x''_\mu - \frac{x'_\mu x'^\nu}{x'^2}x''_\nu}{\sqrt{x'^2}} = \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{x_g'^2}}\left[\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu g_{\nu\gamma}x'^\nu x'^\gamma +\frac{1}{2} \frac{g_{\mu \delta} x'^\delta x'^\alpha}{x'^2_g} \partial_\alpha g_{\nu \gamma} x'^\nu x'^\gamma  - \partial_\nu g_{\mu \gamma} x'^\gamma x'^\nu + \frac{g_{\mu \delta} x'^\delta x'^\nu                      }{x_g'^2}g_{\nu \gamma} x''^\gamma-g_{\mu \gamma} x''^\gamma\right]$$

I will now require $\lambda = \tau$, where $d\tau^2 = \eta_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$ (with $\eta$, not $g$). I will denote $u^\mu = \frac{d x^\mu}{d \tau}$. On applying the constraint of $u^2=\eta_{\mu \nu} u^\mu u^\nu = 1$ freely, the equations of motion become

$$\frac{d u_\mu}{d \tau} = \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{u_g^2}}\left[\frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu g_{\nu\gamma}u^\nu u^\gamma +\frac{1}{2} \frac{g_{\mu \delta} u^\delta u^\alpha}{u^2_g} \partial_\alpha g_{\nu \gamma} u^\nu u^\gamma  - \partial_\nu g_{\mu \gamma} u^\gamma u^\nu + \frac{g_{\mu \delta} u^\delta u^\nu}{u_g^2}g_{\nu \gamma} \frac{d u^\gamma}{d \tau}-g_{\mu \gamma} \frac{d u^\gamma}{d \tau}\right]$$
where $u_g^2$ is shorthand for $g_{\mu \nu} u^\mu u^\nu$. With a little index manipulation, the contraction of the right hand side with $u^\mu$ gives zero; the first three terms cancel, and the last two terms cancel.

---

As an aside, we can write the equations in a more suggestive form:
$$\eta_{\mu \alpha} \frac{x''^\alpha - \frac{x'^\alpha x'^\nu}{x'^2}x''_\nu}{\sqrt{x'^2}} = \frac{\xi g_{\mu \alpha}}{\sqrt{x_g'^2}}\left[-\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\nu \gamma}x'^\nu x'^\gamma+\frac{1}{2} \frac{x'^\alpha}{x'^2_g} ({x_g'^2})'  -x''^\alpha\right]$$

$$\eta_{\mu \alpha}\frac{d u^\alpha}{d\tau} = \frac{\xi g_{\mu \alpha}}{\sqrt{u_g^2}}\left[-\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\nu \gamma}u^\nu u^\gamma+\frac{1}{2} \frac{u^\alpha}{u^2_g} \frac{d u^2_g}{d\tau}  - \frac{d u^\alpha}{d\tau}\right]$$

---

Let's consider the limit $\xi \to \infty$, so that

$$x''^\alpha = -\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\nu \gamma}x'^\nu x'^\gamma+\frac{1}{2} \frac{x'^\alpha}{x'^2_g} ({x_g'^2})'$$

With the parameter choice $\lambda=\tau$ where $d\tau^2 = \eta_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$, our equations of motion won't reduce to the usual form of the geodesic equation, as generically $(x_g'^2)'\neq 0$ for $\lambda=\tau$. We would need the parametrization $\lambda=\tau_g$ where $d\tau_g^2 = g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$ instead to recover the usual form of the geodesic equation, as then we're guaranteed $(x_g'^2)'= 0$ for $\lambda=\tau_g$.

---

In general, it looks like the equations of motion are consistent with $\eta_{\mu \nu} u^\mu \frac{d u^\nu}{d \tau} = 0$ when we start from a parametrization-invariant action with fixed particle mass and then choose the parametrization of the resulting equations of motion to be the SR proper time $\tau$.